# Extract the largest number from a dataframe column containing strings

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, typeerror

I have a pandas dataframe containing columns extracted from a csv file. One of the columns has strings which contain a particular number, I want to extract. It showed a `TypeError`, which I think was because of the object data type of the column, but neither does setting data type of the column during extraction work, nor does `astype` work on the particular column. Earlier, I extracted the same column from the Excel file, and the regex expression worked on it, no problem.

The working head is as follows:

```
  Transaction Date                                        PARTICULARS DEPOSITS WITHDRAWALS Amount Dr/Cr  Calc_Amount  Calc RRN Number RRN-AMT
0       2019-05-30              UPI/914923281641/UPI/raghu.m.v2016@o/        0       32.86  32.86    Dr        32.86     914923281641    0100
1       2019-05-30              UPI/915000512028/UPI/hemanth1999kuma/        0        0.95   0.95    Dr         0.95     915000512028    0100
2       2019-05-30          UPI/RVSL915000512028/UPI/hemanth1999kuma/     0.95           0   0.95    Cr        -0.95     915000512028    0100
3       2019-05-30  UPI/914923451855/UPI/tpmanzoor55@okh/Federal Bank     1.19           0   1.19    Cr        -1.19     914923451855    0100
4       2019-05-30              UPI/914923339262/UPI/ravimaurya8735@/        0        0.94   0.94    Dr         0.94     914923339262    0100
```

From this code:

```
for i, row in bank_statement_30May.iterrows():
    result = [e for e in re.split("[^0-9]",row[1]) if e != '']
    bank_statement_30May.loc[i,"Calc RRN Number"] = max(map(int,result))
```

This is the error from the second code:

```
    result = [e for e in re.split("[^0-9]",row[1]) if e != '']
  File "C:\Users\Suraj Joshi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\re.py", line 213, in split
    return _compile(pattern, flags).split(string, maxsplit)
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

Comment: Sorry, for not being clear, no, I only want the number inside, as you can see sometimes the thing between the UPIs has other stuff as well. I want only the numbers which can be seen on the right most end of the first code block. I assumed these would be the largest numbers throughout anyway, so I used that logic.

Comment: okay, so you already have a column with the largest data, now what do you want to do with `Calc RRN Number` column?

Comment: Nothing, I just want that column. I don't 'already' have it, because this was just a sample data I was working on. I have other csv files to put through this, but if it doesn't work for the sample then it won't work for any of them.

Comment: so `df['new_col']=df.PARTICULARS.str.extract('(\d+)',expand=False)` ?

Comment: Yes, this worked for me, thanks a lot! But I also want to work with the new column as a string (concatenate, extract particular digits, etc.) but the data type of the column is object. Will casting work?

Comment: `.astype(float)` should work. since there might be `NaN` , if not , `s=df.PARTICULARS.str.extract('(\d+)',expand=False)` and then `pd.to_numeric(s,errors='coerce')`

Comment: 1 min, you said you want them as strings? then the col dtype should be `object`. I am closing this since this is a dupe. Let me know if you need any help

Comment: Yes, it is working fine as it is. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean by?:

```
bank_statement_30May['Calc RRN Number'] = bank_statement_30May['Calc RRN Number'].astype(str).applymap(lambda x: int(max(x, key=int)))
```

Comment: Yes, this didn't change anything for me. I read some other answers advising me to change to ('str') but that didn't work either. I don't want to change the Calc RRN Number to string, I want to change the PARTICULARS to strings so that the regex doesn't show typeerror

Comment: @SurajJoshi After this line do: `print(bank_statement_30May)`